# how to update file txt using c++

Tags: c++, file, updates

I want to update data in my txt file use c++, this is explain:
the file .txt have form like this:

```
khanh 123456 0
lien 124123 1
hahaha 125225 0
```

Each line represent of one accout, fist word is username, affter is is password and final is status of this accout (0 is actice, 1 is blocked). Ex: line 2: username is `lien`, password is `124123` and status is `1`
And i want to update the status of one accout base on its username.
Ex: i what to change the status of accout `hahaha` from `0` to `1` when i have string (or array char) contain the string `hahaha` (ex: string = "hahaha" or char* arry = "hahaha")
How can i do that, i find some solution and it just override the first line in txt file, somebody can help me, How to update the character in .txt file like this.

Comment: You cannot overwrite data in a text file. What you need to do is read the **whole file** into memory, make the change you want in memory, and then write the **whole file** out to disk.

Comment: @john your statement is true only when one is changing a variable length field (the  term is quite ambiguous, I meant to say, when one wants to change something whose new value will alter the space required to store that particular part). Here the asker just wants to change the status which is guaranteed to be a single char (`0` or `1`). He can simply store the `streampos` before reading the status and print the new status after seeking to the stored position. He doesn't actually need to read the *whole file*.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can't overwrite the file. The alternative solution is just to get data in a specified format and generate an output of the edited version. This is what I've coded for your requirement:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
    std::ifstream file;
    std::ofstream out;

    std::string str;
    short int status; // status = 0, 1
    int bal, i = 1;

    file.open("test.txt"); // opening test.txt
    out.open("output.txt"); // opening output.txt here, otherwise it'll iterate in loop

    // gets input in this format
    while (file >> str >> bal >> status)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << i << "] " << str << ' ' << bal << ' ' << status << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Account status for this person (1 or 0): ";
        std::cin >> status;
        out << str << ' ' << bal << ' ' << status << std::endl;

        i++;
    }

    file.close();
    out.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Created `ifstream` to read and `ofstream` to write the data into `output.txt` folder. You may see the following example output:

> **Example Output**

```
[1] khanh 123456 0
Account status for this person (1 or 0): 1
[2] lien 124123 1
Account status for this person (1 or 0): 0
[3] hahaha 125225 0
Account status for this person (1 or 0): 0
```

Then you should get this in `output.txt`:

```
khanh 123456 1
lien 124123 0
hahaha 125225 0
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

This is my short code using `seekp` and `tellg`:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::fstream file("data.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    std::string user, pass, query;
    char status;
    std::cin >> query; // input the user whose status you wanna toggle
    while (file >> user >> pass)
        if (user == query) {
            auto pos = file.tellg();
            file >> status;
            file.seekp(pos);
            file << (status == '0' ? '1' : '0');
            break;
        } else {
            file >> status;
        }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file in read and write mode keep in mind if you want to update a value with length different from the old one you need to move all the data below or you can just add spaces to fit fixed length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char name[]="hahaha";
char newvalue='1';

int main(void)
{
   FILE* filePtr = fopen("try.txt", "r+");
   char c;
   bool isvalidname=true;
   int name_idx=0;
   while((c = fgetc(filePtr)) != EOF)
   {
       if(c == '\n')
       {
           isvalidname=true;
       }
       if(c == '\r' || c=='\n')
       {
           continue;
       }

       if( isvalidname && ( name_idx + 1 == strlen(name)))
       {
           isvalidname = false;
       }

       if( isvalidname && (name_idx< strlen(name) && name[name_idx]!=c))
       {
           isvalidname = false;
       }
       if(isvalidname)
       {
           name_idx++;
       }

       if(isvalidname && (name_idx == strlen(name) -1))
       {
           int spaces=0;
           while((c = fgetc(filePtr)) != EOF)
           {
                if(c==' ') spaces++;
                if(spaces==2) 
                {
                    fseek(filePtr, 0, SEEK_CUR);
                    fputc(newvalue, filePtr);
                    break;
                }
           }
       }

   }
   fclose(filePtr);
   return 0;
}
```